# XSD : what is the difference between the namespace and the default namespace

Tags: xml, namespaces, xsd, xml-namespaces

Maybe the question's title is misleading, and that is because I couldn't explain my problem in a single line sentence.

In the [w3school tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_schema.asp), there is this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
           xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    ...
    ...
</xs:schema>
```

The author has stated that: `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` means:

> the elements and data types used in the schema come from the "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" namespace. It also specifies that the elements and data types that come from the "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" namespace should be prefixed with xs.

However, the author has also stated that `targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"` means:

> the elements defined by this schema (note, to, from, heading, body.) come from the "http://www.w3schools.com" namespace.

I have a problem understanding the previous paragraphs. The first one states that the elements come from `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` namespace, though the second paragraph states that the elements come from `http://www.w3schools.com` namespace.

In my opinion, these two sentences conflict with each other.

Could you tell me please which one is correct? and what does each one really mean?

I appreciate your time.

Regards,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Default namespaces, qualified names and prefixes

The *default* namespace is the one that is not mapped to any prefix. You declare it using:

```
xmlns="a-string-that-is-usually-an-uri"
```

If you have such a declaration in an XML file, any unprefixed *element* will belong to that namespace. Unprefixed *attributes* always belong to *no namespace*.

You can have several namespace declarations in an XML document, but only one default namespace in each scope. You also don't need to have any default namespace. A scope consists of the element itself and its descendants. In the document below, there are two default namespaces. The `ns2` namespace replaces `ns1` in the element it is declared in and its descendants:

```
<root xmlns="ns1">
    <text>This is ns1</text>
    <child xmlns="ns2">
        <text>This is ns2</text>
    </child>
</root>
```

There are two `<text>` elements in the document above. Actually they are completely different elements since each one belongs to a different namespace. They have the same *local name* but their qualified names differ.

If you have a declaration for the same namespace such as:

```
xmlns:p="a-string-that-is-usually-an-uri"
```

You are mapping the namespace with a prefix `p` which can be used by any element in the context (considering a well-formed document, not necessarily valid). For a valid document, elements that are part of a namespace should be qualified by it, either as an unprefixed descendant (or self) of an element which declares a default namespace, or as a prefixed descendant (or self) of an element which declares a namespace mapping to that prefix. Prefixes can also be used to qualify attributes.

By using prefixes you can have all declarations at the root element, and qualified elements can mix:

```
<root xmlns:p="ns1" xmlns:q="ns2" xmlns="ns0">
    <p:text>This is ns1</p:text>
    <q:child xmlns="ns2">
        <q:text>This is ns2</q:text>
        <p:text>This is ns1 again!</p:text>
        <text>This is ns0</text>
    </q:child>
</root>
```

Each one of the `<text>` elements above are part of a different namespace.

Take some time to read this guide: [Understanding XML Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx). It's short and if you read it carefully, you'll certainly understand how namespaces in XML work very well. If you wish, you can also read the [XML Namespaces specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) which is the official documentation.

#### Target namespaces in XSD

About the tutorial you are reading. This file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
           xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    ...
    ...
</xs:schema>
```

has *two* namespace declarations, and *one* target namespace declaration. Since it's also a schema, it contains *type definitions* which will belong to the *target namespace*. This may be confusing because the schema is a XML document which declares rules for other XML documents using XML. Treating the XSD document as a plain *XML* document, you have one namespace mapped to the `xs` prefix and another which is the *default* namespace. You could also have legally used different prefixes:

```
<abc:schema xmlns:abc="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
           xmlns:xyz="http://www.w3schools.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <abc:complexType name="MyType"> ...</abc:complexType>
    <abc:element name="myElementOne" type="xyz:MyType" />
    <abc:element name="myElementTwo" type="abc:string" />
</abc:schema>
```

If you look carefully at the example above you might see the associations:

1. The `schema`, `complexType` and `element` elements, plus the `string` type all belong to the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` namespace.
2. There are no elements or attributes in the schema that belong to the `http://www.w3schools.com` namespace, since this is a schema and it's actually defining those elements.
3. The `MyType` complex type is part of the `http://www.w3schools.com` namespace. This is because it's being declared in the schema and the `targetNamespace` of the schema is `http://www.w3schools.com`. Since that namespace is mapped to the `xyz` prefix, then you need to `prefix` it when you *refer* to it That's what is happening in the `type` attribute of the first element, the same way the `type` attribute of the second element refers to the `string` type of the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` namespace.

You could also have written the above schema like this. It would make no difference:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
           xmlns:xyz="http://www.w3schools.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <complexType name="MyType"> ...</complexType>
    <element name="myElementOne" type="xyz:MyType" />
    <element name="myElementTwo" type="string" />
</schema>
```

Note now that there *is* a default namespace, and it's `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`, so all types and elements of that namespace are unprefixed.

It's best, however, to follow conventions and map a prefix to the XSD namespace (usually `xs` or `xsd`).

#### About the conflicting sentences

Actually, they are not conflicting. But they are not well written (they might be, perhaps, in their original context). The first one:

> the elements and data types **used** in the schema come from the "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" namespace. It also specifies that the elements and data types that come from the "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" namespace should be prefixed with xs.

Consider the XSD document as a *regular XML file*. In any XML file, a namespace declaration such as xmlns="ns1" in the root element is declaring that the *unprefixed* elements come from the `ns1` *default* namespace. In the case described by the sentence, the author is referring to all the *prefixed* elements (such as `element`, `complexType`, simpleType`,`sequence`) and types (such as`string`,`integer`,`decimal`) because the`xs` prefix is mapped to the XSD namespace. The author is talking about elements and types **used** in the XML file, not defined.

The next sentence is about `targetNamespace`, which is an attribute specific to the XSD specification. It declares the namespace of all the types:

> targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" means that the elements **defined** by this schema (note, to, from, heading, body.) come from the "http://www.w3schools.com" namespace.

This refers to the *names* you are assigning to types and elements. When you create an *instance* that declares that namespace, then you will be *using* these elements:

```
<note xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com">...</note>
```

or

```
<x:note xmlns:x="http://www.w3schools.com">...</x:note>
```

But in the XSD you are *defining* them. You don't even need to declare `xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"` in the schema *if* you never *refer* (using attributes such as `type`, `ref`, etc.) to any other type or element you created inside it.

Comment: can I add `xmlns="xs"` and write a more compat XSD?

Answer (score 0):

```
   default namespace serve only one purpose, it allows use of namespace qualified xml components without namespace prefix.
```

Just to give you one hint to solve above problems, when you define a component it’s targetNamespace you should consider but when you refer a component think of default namespace(or namespace with prefix).